# Poor text scaling with Qt Quick 1.1 / QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquick2

I am developing a software application using Qt 4.8.4 (MSVC 2010) on a Windows 7 PC. I have just made the switch from the QWidget framework to the **QML / QtQuick 1.1** declarative framework however I have noticed that in QtQuick/QML, text scaling is quite poor. Letters are often cut off or skewed slightly.

**In the image below**, the text has been scaled due to a window resize yet it looks different everytime.

Here is the scaling function that I used:

```
scale: paintedWidth > maxWidth ? Math.max((maxWidth / Math.max(paintedWidth, 1)), 0.1) : 1
```

Basically this scaling function scales the text down only if it is larger then the size of the container that it is in. It works as it should.

**I was just wondering if there is any possible way to improve text scaling in QML/Qt Quick 1.1 and if anyone else has noticed this issue?**

I know that some work has been done in regards to text scaling in QtQuick 2 but unfortunately upgrading our UI to QtQuick 2 is not a possibility right now due to compatibility issues.

[image: Bad QML Text Scaling]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to try is setting `smooth: true`

If you're animating the scaling then you may still notice irregularities due to hinting as the fonts are rendered at different sizes. You may have some success in forcing the Text element into a code path that caches the text to an image, which will then be scaled, rather than painting the text directly:

```
smooth: true
style: Text.Raised
styleColor: "transparent"
```

Another reason for the appearance you're getting may be that the text is not being positioned pixel aligned, i.e. `y` is not a whole number, or `y` of a parent element is not a whole number.

Comment: Yes, you are right, setting smooth true always makes things look quite a bit better. Although I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean by not being pixel aligned? I generally stick to using anchors for laying out my QML. I guess what you are suggesting is that it might help to calculate the height of the scaled text and make certain that is a whole number?

Comment: This is not pixel aligned: `Text { y: 0.5; text: "hello" }`.  If you're using anchors and whole numbers you'll be fine.

Comment: Ah gotcha, yea I generally always stick to anchor-based layouts for this reason.

Comment: I didn't notice any difference adding `style: Text.Raised
styleColor: "transparent"` to a QML text element before scaling. Thank you for your suggestions though, I'll mark your response as true because setting smooth did help, still not as great as other platforms, but better. I hope this has been addressed in Qt Quick 2.